# Why does max number of threads decrease when I increase max heap size?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, heap-memory

This test shows the max number of threads that can be created in Java

```
    System.out.println("Max memory  " + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024 + "M");
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            };
        };
        try {
            t.start();
        } catch (Error e) {
            System.out.println("Max threads " + i);
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

When I run it with default heap size (256M) I get

```
Max memory  247M
Max threads 2247
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:691)
    at test.Test1.main(Test1.java:19)
```

when I increase max heap size to 512M I get

```
Max memory  494M
Max threads 1906
...
```

when I increase max heap size to 1024M I get

```
Max memory  989M
Max threads 1162
...
```

That is, more heap memory fewer threads. Why is that?

Comment: Could we see your `java -version`?

Comment: It is HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.7.0_21 on Windows 7

Comment: More threads = less heap

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Each thread requires a stack. The more memory you allocate to the heap, the less memory is left for the stacks.

This will be particularly acute if you're using a 32-bit JVM, since the process will have no more than 4GB of address space for *everything* (the code, the heap, the stacks etc). I cannot reproduce this behaviour on my 64-bit box, where "Max threads" remains the same regardless of how much memory I allocate to the heap.

It is worth noting that many operating systems enable you to tweak the size of the stack. On Unix this is done using `ulimit -s`.

Comment: Do you have any sources? Also is it possible to specify the stack size (either total or per-thread)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that increasing the heap size (and using all of it) lowers the amount of memory the OS has available for creating new threads, so it can't create as many threads as before.